# how to update nested json_data in delta table pyspark/hive

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

```
(Databricks)
%sql 
select * from df2

jsonData
--------
{"col1":"AA","col2":"BB","col3":"CC","col4":"DD"}
```

I want to update col4 value as TT like `"col4":"TT"`

I tried with below code:

```
update df2 set jsonData = JSON_SET(jsonData '$.col4', 'TT')
```

and

```
update df2 set jsonData = JSON_MODIFY(jsonData '$.col4', 'TT')
```

Getting below error:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'JSON_MODIFY'. 
This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function 
registered in the database 'default'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`from_json`** function to flatten out json into columns then update **`col4`** finally recreate json object using **`to_json`** function.

**`Example`**:

```
df.show(10,False)
#+-------------------------------------------------+
#|jsonData                                         |
#+-------------------------------------------------+
#|{"col1":"AA","col2":"BB","col3":"CC","col4":"DD"}|
#+-------------------------------------------------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.selectExpr("from_json(jsonData,'col1 string,col2 string,col3 string,col4 string') as jsn_str").\
select("jsn_str.*").\
withColumn("col4",lit("TT")).\
withColumn("jsonData",to_json(struct(col("col1"),col("col2"),col("col3"),col("col4")))).\
select("jsonData").\
show(10,False)
#+-------------------------------------------------+
#|jsonData                                         |
#+-------------------------------------------------+
#|{"col1":"AA","col2":"BB","col3":"CC","col4":"TT"}|
#+-------------------------------------------------+
```